# Pointers to Structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

When trying to compile the following code, I am getting a warning that line 18 makes integer from pointer without cast and that 19 and 20 are incompatible types in assignment.  I am new to structures in C, and can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct song
{       char title[70];
};

struct playlist
{       struct song songs[100];
};

void title_sort(struct playlist * list,int len)
{       int swapped = 1,i;
        char hold;
        while (swapped)
        {       swapped = 0;
                for (i = 0;i < len - 1; i++)
                {       if (list->songs[i].title > list->songs[i+1].title)
                        {       hold = list->songs[i].title;
                                list->songs[i].title = list->songs[i+1].title;
                                list->songs[i+1].title = hold;
                                swapped = 1;
                        }
                }
        }
}

int main()
{       struct playlist playlist;
        int i;
        for (i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        {       fgets(playlist.songs[i].title,70,stdin);
        }
        title_sort(&playlist,5);
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        {       printf("%s",playlist.songs[i].title);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't compare strings in C with >. You need to use `strcmp`. Also `hold` is `char` but title is `char [70]`. You could copy pointers to strings but arrays can't be copied with just `=`.

You could use `strcpy` like this:

```
void title_sort(struct playlist * list,int len)
{       int swapped = 1,i;
        char hold[70];
        while (swapped)
        {       swapped = 0;
                for (i = 0;i < len - 1; i++)
                    {       if (strcmp (list->songs[i].title, list->songs[i+1].title) > 0)
                            {       strcpy (hold, list->songs[i].title);
                                strcpy (list->songs[i].title, list->songs[i+1].title);
                                strcpy (list->songs[i+1].title,hold);
                                swapped = 1;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

But please note that in C you need to check things like the lengths of strings, so the above code is dangerous. You need to either use `strncpy` or use `strlen` to check the lengths of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use strings like that C. Strings are essentially a simple array of characters in C without specialized operators like =, < etc. You need to use string functions like `strcmp` and `strcpy` to do the string manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific : following is wrong

```
if (list->songs[i].title > list->songs[i+1].title)
```

Do it this way:

```
if( strcmp (list->songs[i].title , list->songs[i+1].title) > 0 )
```

Comment: You're missing a `> 0)` at the end of your snippet there.

Answer (score 0):

- `char hold` needs to be something else, perhaps `char *hold`, perhaps an array.
- C doesn't have array assignment, although it does have structure assignment, you will need to rework that

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue, on line 18, is caused by two problems.  Firstly, the variable `hold` can only hold a single `char` value, and you're trying to assign an array of 70 `char`s to it.

First you'll need to make `hold` the correct type:

```
char hold[70];
```

Now, there's another problem - arrays can't just be assigned using the `=` operator.  You have to use a function to explicitly copy the data from one array to another.  Instead of your current line 18, you could use:

```
memcpy(hold, list->songs[i].title, 70);
```

You then need to do the same thing for lines 19 and 20:

```
memcpy(list->songs[i].title, list->songs[i+1].title, 70);
memcpy(list->songs[i+1].title, hold, 70);
```

Alternatively, you could write a loop and swap the two titles one char at a time.

In a similar fashion, you can't compare two strings with the simple `<` operator - you need to use a function for this, too (eg. `strcmp`).